# Why is ffmpeg modifying my 5.1 channel layout?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

I have an AC3 sound file in 5.1 surround, and an MOV file with no sound. I am using FFMPEG to add the sound to the MOV file, and although it works succesfully, for some reason it is modifying the layout of the sound channels, and looking at the audio waveforms it even looks as though it may be mixing them, which is very worrying.

The layout of audio channels in the AC3 file is: L, R, C, LFE, Ls, Rs.

Here is the command I am using to combine them:

```
ffmpeg -i [path to MOV] -i [path to AC3] -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 [path to output MOV]
```

When I look at the final MOV (with sound added) in Mediainfo, the layout of audio channels has changed to: L, C, R, Ls, Rs, LFE. And again, as I shared above when I look at the waveform of the 6 audio channels in the new MOV not only are they out of order, but one of them looks unfamilliar compared to the original AC3 file, which leads me to believe it may even be doing some mixing?

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add more specificity to my command to preserve the audio's integrity?